# Org Link to png file displays as wildcard rather than the image file itself

Tags: org-mode, debugging

When I click on a link to a certain recent screenshot, this is shown rather than the image  itself.

```
  /Users/satibodhi/Creation/notes:
  wildcard 楷{氵尸}.png
  -rw-r--r--@ 1 satibodhi  staff  2373 Jul  3 09:24 楷{氵尸}.png
```

All my other image links show properly with `org-display-inline-images`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file name contains an opening curly bracket. [`org-open-at-point`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/release_9.1.13/lisp/org.el#L10720-L10721) uses the characters `*` and `{` to detect shell-style patterns in the file name and runs `dired` instead of `org-open-file`.

What you see is that dired buffer.

Comment: What is the dired function used for and how do you switch that off?