# Open a wildcard-link directly rather than through dired

Tags: org-mode, dired, org-link, wildcard

In Org mode, when I open a link (`C-c C-o`) to a file such as `file:something.pdf`, the file is opened with my system PDF viewer. However, if the link contains a wildcard, such as `file:3_o*.pdf`, Emacs opens it through `dired` instead (also mentioned in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51365), and selecting the pdf opens it within Emacs.

I would instead have it open the first match of that pattern in the system application - and don't highlight it in red. I'd also be fine with a custom link type if this can't be done otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs lisp newbie here. As far as I know there are two ways to change this behaviour without changing Org's source code: either a custom link type, or an advice around `org-link-open` (see `(elisp) Advising Functions`).

## Custom link type

I've opted for the former, as the latter changed between Org versions (you need an advice around `org-link-open` in Org 9.3.6 an and advice around `org-open-at-point` in 9.1.9):

```lisp
(require 'org)

(org-add-link-type "first" 'org-first-open)

(defun org-first-open (pattern)
  "Open the first file that matches PATTERN.
PATTERN should match at least one file."
  (let ((candidates (file-expand-wildcards pattern)))
    (if candidates (org-open-file (car candidates))
      (error "No file matches \"%s\"" pattern))))
```

You can now use `first:3_o*.pdf` to get the first result of the wildcard expansion.

The [manual has some more information on custom types](https://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-Hyperlink-Types.html#Adding-Hyperlink-Types), for example customization options. Note that the current guide uses plists to define the link type via `org-add-link-type`, but that's a recent(?) addition. I opted for the earlier, still valid syntax from 9.1.

## Advice for `org-link-open`

This advice was tested in Org version 9.3.6 and 9.4-19. It will definitely not work in 9.1.9. Other versions are untested.

```lisp
(defun my-org-expand-file-link (link)
  "Expand a pattern in LINK to the first matching file.

Returns the original LINK if no file matches the pattern in LINK or if it is not
a link of type 'file:'.  See info node `(org)External links' for more information."
  (let ((type (org-element-property :type link))
        (path (org-element-property :path link)))
    (cond
     ((equal type "file")
      (let ((candidates (file-expand-wildcards path)))
        (if candidates
            (org-element-put-property (org-element-copy link) :path (car candidates))
          link)))
     (t link))))

(defun my-org-link-open-advice (orig-fun link &rest args)
  "Advice for ORIG-FUN that expands patterns in 'file:' LINKs.
See `my-org-expand-file-link' for more information.
Optional argument ARGS are passed as-is."
  (apply orig-fun (my-org-expand-file-link link) args))

(advice-add 'org-link-open :around #'my-org-link-open-advice)
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I'd love to hear about the advice version (simply for the latest org version) - that way, the links would still be usable without my config, just not as convenient.

Comment: @Xerus err, let me try to recreate that. That was my first solution, but it didn't work on the old `(org-version)`. Might take some time, as I need to update Emacs on this machine first.

Comment: @Xerus added the `(advice-add ...)` variant. Keep in mind that this is probably the third time I wrote emacs lisp that's not part of a `(use-package)` in my configuration, so it's probably not idiomatic elisp. I'm especially not sure about whether `org-element-copy` is actually necessary.

Comment: Cross-stack-exchange note: I've asked for a review of the code above on CR: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250783/21002